# How to protect functions which are called with different contexts from breaking?

Tags: javascript, oop, functional-programming, typeof, duck-typing

I'm fairly new to javascript and now I learned how calling functions with a context works.

Here is a simple example that poses a question in my head. Lets say we have this example:

```
var myObj = {
    bar: function() {
      console.log("Lets got to the bar!");
    }
}

/* how can this be protected from errors, 
 * if a passed object doesn't contain bar */
function foo()
{
   this.bar();
} 

foo.call(myObj);
```

Now, how can foo be protected of breaking? In some OOP language (lets say Java) this would be implemented lets say via an interface. So in that case if the object being instantiated hasn't implemented the interface method, the compiler would through an error so the compiler protects the code/program from being faulty (in this case of course).

```
public interface MyInterface
{
   public void bar();
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
   public void bar()
   {
     System.println("Lets go to the bar");
   }
}

MyInterface m = new MyClass();
m.bar(); // if bar isn't implemented the compiler would warn/break
```

Note: I'm not that good in Java so sorry for any syntax or other errors, but I hope you get the point.

So to sum up, as I see that in both cases in both languages one can achieve polymorphism, right? Now if so for the Javascript example, how can one protect it from breaking, are there any patterns or tricks? Does `typeof this.bar === function` work? If so, who guarantees the SW quality if the programmer forgets this, I'm asking this kind of question because Java has the compiler to warn the programmer about the mistake, does JS have something similar, some quality check tool?

Comment: `this.hasOwnProperty('bar') && typeof this.bar === 'function' ` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: What if I use prototype hierarchy, I see from the article it doesn't support it?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a dynamic interpeted* language. There isn't a compiler step to check references. Some tools (jsline) and IDEs (VS, Webstorm) can perform some design-time checks for you, but there's no true type safety. This is largely seen as a feature, not a bug.

There's an array of tricks to work around this (*.hasOwnProperty, typeof x === 'function', storing self references, context binding*) but mostly, if you want a type safety, you want a different language.

My recommendation is [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). It has a Java/C-like syntax, with some familiar OOP features, like classes, interface (and thus, sane polymorphism) and generic types, and transpiles to javascript in moments.

Comment: "This is largely seen as a feature, not a bug." As I see it, it makes the language flexible, but also more error prone.

Comment: My background is oop/framework programming, so I tend to look at the flexibility of dynamic languages in terms of defect potential :)

Answer (score -1):

If you use a constructor to create your object you can use Javascript's builtin class member ship checking features. An example is below.

```
class MyClass {
  bar() { console.log("Lets got to the bar!")}
}

function foo() {
  if ( this instanceof MyClass ) {
   this.bar();
  }
  else {
    console.log('this is not a member of the MyClass');
  }
}

foo.call(new MyClass);
```

Be warned that Javascript's type checking is horribly unreliable and you probably should not use it. If your object contains the same prototype anywhere in it's prototype chain as the class you are testing it for membership in, instanceof will return true.

**Quick and dirty duck typing example**

This will throw if you give it an object without the properties you are checking for, but you get the idea.

```
class MyClass {
   constructor() {
     this.feathers = 'white';
     this.feet = 'webbed';
   }

  bar() { console.log("Lets got to the bar!")}
}

function foo() {
  if (
    this.hasOwnProperty('feathers') && 
    this.hasOwnProperty('feet') && 
    this.feathers === 'white' &&
    this.feet === 'webbed'
  )
  {
    this.bar();
  }
  else {
    console.log('this is not a member of the MyClass');
  }
}

foo.call(new MyClass);
```

Comment: You'd use duck typing for an interface in JS, though

Comment: So, the problem you are solving here aplies only when prototypes are used? And if I get it right, duck typing is when you put properties which sole purpose is to verify that one is using the right object and that it contains the wanted method bar(), or?

Comment: Look up how `instanceof` works and you'll answer your own question in terms of how it relates to prototypes.  In Duck typing, you don't put properties on objects for the purpose of determining its type. You attempt to determine its type by doing your own tests to determine if it is the correct type. How you do the duck typing is up to you.